# Conectar ao SQLServer usando Windows 10?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans

Estou usando o Windows 10 e tenho que conectar a uma base de dados SQLServer 2000
usando a linha de comando em uma aplicação java. Porém estou recebendo um erro.

```
 run:
ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:
```

É possível sistemas windows 10 conectar a base de dados antigas como SQLServer 2000

em uma classe java, feita no NETBEANS dei esse Comando:

```
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://servido:1433","sa","senha");
```

Comment: Você adicionou ao seu projeto a lib contendo o driver do sqlserver? Baixe [deste link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/mt683464(v=sql.110).aspx) e adicione ao classpath do seu projeto. O erro é porque ele não localizou o driver do sqlserver.

Comment: sim o sqljdbc.jar ou com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc

Comment: Tente este https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=21599 o link que te passei parece não ser compativel com versoes anteriores a 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o drive jtds vai te ajudar, já utilizei ele para conectar no 2000.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/